# Too many authorization bearers in MFP 8.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I've followed the steps provided in https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/protecting-external-resources/ to protect an external resource and https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/resource-request/javascript/ to call via Cordova.

I'm making 2 request to the same REST method, which is protected with the scope "aovLogin".

It seems that every call is generating a new bearer token, which needs 4 extra calls to MFP.

Also, the first time a method is called, it makes several extra calls (it always goes http 401, then 403 then 200, making extra calls to MFP in the middle). If i have a very granular API, it's making a lot of extra calls.

I've seen that the server API has a cache for the bearers and the scope is configured for being valid for 10 minutes.

Why is the client sending so many authorization requests?

```
POST /com.costaisa.app.api/api/mfprest/delegation/detail/private HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

----------

POST /mfp/api/preauth/v1/preauthorize HTTP/1.1
{"scope":"","client_id":"3deccec7-3f18-4ee2-8464-de90a7c64685"}

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
{"errorCode":"INVALID_CLIENT_ID","errorMsg":"Invalid client ID."}

------

POST /mfp/api/registration/v1/self HTTP/1.1
{"signedRegistrationData":{"header":"XXXXX","payload":"XXXXX","signature":"XXXXX"}}

HTTP/1.1 201 Created

-----

POST /mfp/api/preauth/v1/preauthorize HTTP/1.1
{"scope":"","client_id":"84c45e4a-b75d-4125-ab9a-98f390d5bd3a"}

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
{"successes":{"clockSynchronization":{"serverTimeStamp":1480322130967}}}

--------

GET /mfp/api/az/v1/authorization?response_type=code&scope=&client_id=84c45e4a-b75d-4125-ab9a-98f390d5bd3a&redirect_uri=http://mfpredirecturi&isAjaxRequest=true&x=0.1757133661526875 HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 302 Found

------

POST /mfp/api/az/v1/token HTTP/1.1
XXXXX

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
{"access_token":"XXXXX","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3599,"scope":""}

---

POST /com.costaisa.app.api/api/mfprest/delegation/detail/private HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer XXXXX
{"idDelegation":"0801"}

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

---

POST /mfp/api/preauth/v1/preauthorize HTTP/1.1
{"scope":"aovLogin","client_id":"84c45e4a-b75d-4125-ab9a-98f390d5bd3a"}

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
{"successes":{"clockSynchronization":{"serverTimeStamp":1480322131320}},"challenges":{"aovLogin":{"remainingAttempts":5,"errorMsg":null}}}

---

POST /mfp/api/preauth/v1/preauthorize HTTP/1.1
{"challengeResponse":{"aovLogin":{"username":"XXXXX","tokenSEA":"XXXXX"}},"scope":"aovLogin","client_id":"84c45e4a-b75d-4125-ab9a-98f390d5bd3a"}

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
{"successes":{"aovLogin":{"user":{"id":"XXXXX","displayName":"XXXXX","authenticatedAt":1480322139874,"authenticatedBy":"aovLogin","attributes":{"tokenSEA":"XXXXX"}}},"clockSynchronization":{"serverTimeStamp":1480322139874}}}


--------

GET /mfp/api/az/v1/authorization?response_type=code&scope=aovLogin&client_id=84c45e4a-b75d-4125-ab9a-98f390d5bd3a&redirect_uri=http://mfpredirecturi&isAjaxRequest=true&x=0.5223292209780417 HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 302 Found

---

POST /mfp/api/az/v1/token HTTP/1.1
XXXXX

HTTP/1.1 200 OK


{"access_token":"XXXXX","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":599,"scope":"aovLogin"}


---

POST /com.costaisa.app.api/api/mfprest/delegation/detail/private HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer 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.eyJpc3MiOiJjb20uaWJtLm1mcCIsInN1YiI6Ijg0YzQ1ZTRhLWI3NWQtNDEyNS1hYjlhLTk4ZjM5MGQ1YmQzYSIsImF1ZCI6ImNvbS5pYm0ubWZwIiwiZXhwIjoxNDgwMzIyNzM5ODc0LCJzY29wZSI6ImFvdkxvZ2luIn0.jGJAhZaV6NFHZKj-LKBmJ6Gqb7ZrZX20xDKEPkNtORZ1tanLo8MSklY2HogK-wKs7APIuWESLSsskrwR9p0EnrmHgUYZf3BPY9HDUSBojUN9-vd_I9kavcg34Hes1KTvYG4Wi-9XbZQ2T1-SbHhn-mqsToeLIGBGkzsugwQG9tIKG3Qr0BixDIfuhxux4Gdo30HCyn9SB5ZaY5wdxaD2_kJjnJih_SsAuuXRNAXEO_PgExnZ6Mr1qyqyOfwc3k9jmgRpuEQigYYRYOP-Tvs_i59IVYOdpsQ70gi-Ky09orx5Jy3hVJv-J45Dx7FHdR3ZPTn7pYW7IRmRo4CZ2COoCg

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
.....

--- CALL AGAIN, new bearer is generated

POST /mfp/api/az/v1/introspection HTTP/1.1

POST /mfp/api/preauth/v1/preauthorize HTTP/1.1

GET /mfp/api/az/v1/authorization?XXX HTTP/1.1

POST /mfp/api/az/v1/token HTTP/1.1


POST /com.costaisa.app.api/api/mfprest/delegation/detail/private HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer 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.eyJpc3MiOiJjb20uaWJtLm1mcCIsInN1YiI6IjM1NDcyYWNhLWVlNmItNGNhZi04OGQ2LWQxY2ExNjQ0NzM4NyIsImF1ZCI6ImNvbS5pYm0ubWZwIiwiZXhwIjoxNDgwMzM5OTU0NjE2LCJzY29wZSI6ImFvdkxvZ2luIn0.JSm3nrW6BD5i66GossHYM4-6GqQfC-ZSH5P-X4M9mws2jBNvCkFKgv_XbRAb3km-0NMZz3FHsrY_0h0dx7fpJYiR9CIjaY-PFw75zdKbyEpzbhAX7OjZtYOtZblKEYLkT8mH-0mLc6VE_YBPFd2q55HMmECCLirAAdWwzMGgEzL02OKTd1GVuJyjqjlxeOJypFglaHezuByd6eGVMFJvnfDX3h_o6k8sWcv-g7UFa8jtcMNZpbzFOYG9Q2nGQ-oYIt17QyF4CVKPMN4anMwRRQ_2cjuvg-1ZuU450hxBX3u09wBxJ21mQklgg72t7fdLKgT7EIPmQlPP3wrX9qzy7A

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Update:

- The HTTP 401 and 403 calls to the external resource and serveral calls to MFP can be avoided if the scope is send in WLResourceRequest
- It generates a new token calling an external resource using an absolute URL but also calling a standard protected adapter using a relative URL

Sample calling a protected adapter:

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(
    "/adapters/AOS42_AOV_API/resource/protectedResource",
    WLResourceRequest.GET,
    {'scope' : 'aovLogin'} // it avoids 401 and 403 responses
);

resourceRequest.send().then(
    function (response) {
        alert("response ok protectedResource " + response.responseText);
    },
    function (response) {
        alert("response ko protectedResource " + response.responseText);
    }
);
```

Sample calling an external resource:

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(
    "https://someurl.com/someApp/protectedResource",
    WLResourceRequest.GET,
    {'scope' : 'aovLogin'} // it avoids 401 and 403 responses
);
```

Update 2:

We've made a change: Instead of calling to a protected external resource, receiving HTTP 401 and then sending the challenge, now we call to WLAuthorizationManager.login before.

In Android, it continues calling MFP 3 times before each call, but now the server returns the same Bearer Token.

The same Cordova Application calling the same Rest API protected by MFP and using the same security adapter in MFP works perfectly fine in iOS.
Once the bearer is obtained, we see only calls to the external API.

Comment: Are you saying that your second call, even though it happened within less than 10 minutes, generated a new token?

Comment: Also you mentioned external resource. If you use a regular internal resource (adapter) do you see the same behavior?

Comment: Yes, it obtains a new bearer (4 calls to MFP) and then calls the external resource every time. I've captured the HTTP request and the server accepts the same token for 10 minutes at least. I've tested a protected adapter and it works the same. I've updated the question with this information

Comment: Are you testing on ios or android? And does it change anything?

Comment: I can only test in Android. I've been doing the server adaptations and testing with the minimal JS. In the meantime, a collegue is adding a component in the real application with NodeJS + Angular2 and making the integration in the build process. Maybe tomorrow we could test in iOS

Comment: So far I don't have ideas so no answer, but please update with the result of your iOS tests as well.

Comment: New update. Should i file a PMR?

Comment: Yes, please open a PMR so it could be further investigated.

Comment: PMR 86574 100 838

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has been resolved in a just-released iFix for MobileFirst Foundation 8.0. The build number is 8.0.0.0-IF20170125-0919. Please login to IBM Fix Central to download the iFix.

The associated APAR is:
PI74988 MULTIPLE AUTHORIZATION CALLS ARE MADE FOR EACH REST CALL IN ANDROID APPLICATION

Since you're using Cordova, I believe updating the cordova-plugin-mfp plug-in to @8.0.2017012210  should suffice.